# Meaning of "growing up" in this sentence "how many of us here today saw our dads enough growing up?"

Tags: grammar

I'm a beginner.

I'm confused about what grammar is about the "growing up" in this sentence.

Shouldn't it be "when you're growing up"??

> How many of us saw our dads enough growing up?

Comment: There’s an implied “when we were” after “enough”.

Comment: so, the full sentence should be "How many of us saw our dads enough when we were 
 growing up?".

Comment: Not "should be": the original sentence is fine as is. But yes, that's what it means.

Comment: The sentence could be rearranged: “How many of us here today, growing up, saw our dads enough?”  Is that clearer?